# NSWindow going behind main window

Tags: macos, cocoa, osx-lion, nswindow

I have a main window for my application. When a button is clicked I present another window (smaller one). This is shown above the main window by default. From the smaller window I have a option to navigate to a browser page. When I do this my both windows go to background and browser will be at the front. After that when I try to click my smaller window, it's coming behind the main window. I need it to come above main window. Is there any way out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [addChildWindow:ordered:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> After the childWindow is added as a child of the window, it is
>   maintained in relative position indicated by orderingMode for
>   subsequent ordering operations involving either window. While this
>   attachment is active, moving childWindow will not cause the window to
>   move (as in sliding a drawer in or out), but moving the window will
>   cause childWindow to move.